# MPMoviePlayer Buffer size/Adjustment

Tags: ios, streaming, buffer, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have been using `MPMovieplayer` and the `playableDuration` to check the available duration of a movie.

The duration always seems to be ~1 second further than my current duration and basically I would like to increase this.

I have tried to use the `prepareToPlay` but this seems to do nothing noticeable to the playable Duration.

I have tried to set as many parameters as possible to attempt to try and change the value via setting the defaults pre-emptively such as the `MPMovieSourceType`, `MediaType` and alike, but all to no avail.

Just to clear a few things up firstly: I am using both `MPMoviePlayer` and `AVplayer` which both play different streams simultaneously as the video/audio I am using is split.

**EDIT**

Seems like I overlooked the file size affecting the stream and should have read more in the apple resources then elsewhere, but as far as I can tell the issue is:  the file size is too large and therefore a server side media segmenter has to be implemented.

[Apple Resource on Media Segmenting](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/HTTPStreamingArchitecture/HTTPStreamingArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH101-SW2)